# Invalid scope in staging, but working on local

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, php-curl

I would like to implement a facebook login to my website. This website is here to learn by myself, this is why i do not use facebook php dependencies. I already done this, but with the version 2.3, I choose the lastest one: the version 3.3, and my app is running (isn't in test mode)

I started to just get my basic profil (just the last_name, first_name and the facebook ID). All working as expected.
Once done, I thought the my app was greatfully configured, then I played with the [facebook playground](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to discover permissions and graph fields.

The first problem occur: i couldn't get my friendlists (with the playground). I had the "friends" permission in my toekn, then I hask the id's friendlists, I always get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "DLbDoKNTwEh"
  }
}
```

This is not really important, i decided to put this aside: I disabled it. Then, without friendlists scope, all everything is working properly in my local server: I decided to push it to my staging server (an heroku app). Then I had the callback url in my facebook config.
And, I nerver succeed to login to my facebook account in heroku server.
The following class method allow me to manage my social api. Thus method redirect the user to an url, to get the social token from the code returned:

```
private function getRedirectURL(Social $social){
        return File::fromRoot(Folder::getVersionFolder().'redirections/'.$social->getType().'.php')->getUrl(['protocol' => 'https']);
    }


    public function attemptLogin($social = null){
        $social = Social::get($social);

        switch(Social::TYPES[$social->getType()]){
            case Social::TYPES['facebook']:
                return 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . CONFIG::SOCIAL['facebook']['id'] . '&redirect_uri='.$this->getRedirectURL($social).'&scope=user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,user_photos,user_friends,user_gender,user_link,user_age_range,email,public_profile';
                break;
            case Social::TYPES['instagram']:
                return 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='.CONFIG::SOCIAL['instagram']['id'].'&redirect_uri='.$this->getRedirectURL($social).'&response_type=code';
                break;
            case 'google':
                return 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri='.$this->getRedirectURL($social).'&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id='.CONFIG::SOCIAL['google']['id'].'&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&access_type=offline';
                break;


        }

        return Folder::fromRoot(Folder::getVersionFolder())->getUrl();
    }
```

This link return me this error when I try to login in:

> Invalid Scopes: user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location, user_photos, user_friends, user_gender, user_link, user_age_range. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: about friendlists (make sure you understand the difference between "friends" and "friendlists"): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/ (it is deprecated)

Comment: You get the “Invalid Scopes” message usually if you put your app into production mode already, but did not get the permissions reviewed & approved yet. Put the app in development mode while you are developing it.